# how do i find the sum of all the numbers in an array in c#

Tags: c#, sum

How do I shorten my code to find the sum of numbers in an array.

```
var numbers= new double[4]; 
numbers[0]=12.7;
numbers[1]=10.4;
numbers[2]=9.2;
numbers[3]=8.5;
var results=numbers[0]+numbers[1]+numbers[2]+numbers[3];
Console.WriteLine(results);
```

My goal is to shorten this code to something like `results = sum(numbers[0:5])` like in python.

Please, what is he c# equivalent of this ?

Answer (score 3):

Use could use `.Sum` (from System.Linq)

e.g to sum all:

```
var results = numbers.Sum(n => n);
```

If you need only of the first results, e.g. the sum of the first 3, you could do:

```
var resultsFirst3 = numbers.Take(3).Sum(n => n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Julian's answer is the best approach, you could also do it without the use of LINQ (not saying that you should). A more classic approach would be something like this:

```
var numbers= new double[4]; 
numbers[0]=12.7;
numbers[1]=10.4;
numbers[2]=9.2;

double sum = 0;

foreach (var num in numbers)
{
    sum += num;
}

Console.WriteLine("The sum is: " + sum);
```

As you can see, this is quite a bit longer, less elegant and (if you ask me) harder to read. So I would deffinitely go for the LINQ approach.